# keeping javascript changes when I use the browser back button (jquery, rails 3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, back-button

I've got a gallery of images where the user can click a little 'x' to archive the image (i.e. send it below-the-fold in the gallery). When the page is loaded it separates the images into the sets above and below the fold based on a boolean field in the database model. When you click the 'x' jquery makes an ajax call to my backend to update the boolean flag, and then I use js to take the image and append it to the right section (i.e. if you just archived it it goes below the line, otherwise it's added back to the top section). All of this framework works great, but if you navigate away from the page and then use the browser back button to return, the images show up in their original location (not 'archived' below the fold). How can I make the changes made by the javascript be the version that gets stored and then returned to by the back button?

images_controller.rb

```
def archive
  @image.archived = !@image.archived
  @image.save
  respond to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

gallery html:

```
<div id="images-active" class="images">
  <% @images.each do |img| %>
    <%= content_tag_for(:div, active, :class=>"goal_blurb") do %>
      <div class="image">
        <%= link_to(archive_path(img), :method=>'get', :remote=>true ) do %>
          <span class="close">X</span>
        <% end %>
        <%= image_tag( img.path ) %>
      </div>
    <%end%>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="images" id='images-archive'>
<% @arch_images.each do |img| %>
    <%= content_tag_for(:div, active, :class=>"goal_blurb") do %>
      <div class="image">
        <%= link_to(archive_path(img), :method=>'get', :remote=>true ) do %>
          <span class="close">X</span>
        <% end %>
        <%= image_tag( img.path ) %>
      </div>
    <%end%>
<% end %>
</div>
```

archive.js.erb

```
$('#<%= dom_id(@image) %>').fadeOut('slow', function(){
  $(this).appendTo('#images-<%=@image.archived ? 'archive':'active'%>').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the browser simply takes the page as it is stored in it's cache. You would have to force the client to get a fresh copy of it by not allowing this page to be cached.

Try this :

```
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
```

Comment: This will simply re-load the page to its oroginal state, not the start AFTER javascript actions have made changes.

Comment: Forcing the client to get a fresh copy sounds like the right direction. I've included this meta tag and it's not forcing a refresh when I navigate back to the page through the browser's stack, though.

Comment: Hm, I conditionally take that back. I tried it in Safari, and it works there. I wonder if it is a case of aggressive caching on the part of Chrome, or is this a solution with spotty support across browsers?

Comment: the pragma don't work with older IE. You have to use `<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">`, and you can also use `<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">`.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is because browser cached your JS response as text and fails to execute it. I haven't figured out clearly why it fails yet but you can prevent JS caching by adding `before_action` method:

```
before_action :set_no_cache, only: [...]
```

with those code inside set_no_cache method:

```
if request.format == "js"
  response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate' # HTTP 1.1.
  response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache' # HTTP 1.0.
  response.headers['Expires'] = '0' # Proxies.
end
```

Tested in chrome, safari, firefox.

Answer (score 0):

One technique is to use a URL hash:

```
yoursite.com#state_1=1&state2=55
```

As you change state, you add some meaningful information to the current URL using `document.location.hash='...'` to store it. This can tell you which section the user is on, then which image they are viewing.

When you re-load the page, look for the hash, and execute the appropriate JS to restore the UI to the previous state.

This is pretty handy because the user can reload or bookmark the page and it will still work.

Comment: I'm not sure if we're on the same page about the issue I'm trying to solve -- the application is database backed, and the ajax is updating the database, so there is no issue with page reloads or bookmarking. The problem is if I update the database ajaxly and then use JQuery appendTo() to move an image from the 'active' bucket into the 'archived' bucket after the ajax call returns. Then I navigate to another page, and then use the browser's back button to go back through the stack the changes that I made in the dom using jQuery don't get saved in the browser's stack.